# How to enforce low FPS in v4l2 for /dev/video0?

Tags: video, webcam, frame-rate, v4l2

I am running 2 Philips SPC900NC Webcams under Debian Jessie (3.4 and 4.7 kernels). The cam is doing great in low light situations, if FPS can be reduced to 10 FPS or even 5 FPS. This works fine e.g. by recording a video with ffmpeg via:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 5 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 test.mp4
```

But with surveillance tools like Motion and ZoneMinder, the cam always defaults to 15FPS - independently of any FPS rates I set in these programs. Also running "v4l2-ctl --set-parm 5" gets overwritten when Motion or ZoneMinder are started (I checked with: v4l2-ctl --get-parm).

I played with v4l2loopback and the following config is actually enforcing 5fps: /dev/video0 -> ffmpeg -> /dev/video1 -> Zoneminder. But the problem is additional CPU consumption of ffmpeg.

Is there any possibility to archive 5 FPS by enforcing the FPS in v4l2 natively (avoiding adding v4l2loopback/ffmpeg to the mix) ?

Answer (score 0):

if it is this what you looking for:
`v4l2loopback-ctl set-fps 25 /dev/video0`

[Source](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback).